# Firebase keeps updating using Update method, and does not stop?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a date tracking application, which basically allows users to have 30 days set holiday allowance, for every day they book/choose it will deduct it from the overall allowance. The problem is that every time I try updating the firebase database with a new value, it infinitley loops, and does not stop. How do I update the database once?

My Database code:

```
 public void updateDaysCalc() {
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        //get current user information
        final String userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        final DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                Long currentAllowance = documentSnapshot.getLong("annualHoliday");

                if (currentAllowance > 0) {

                    long minusDays = countDays();
                    long newHolidayAllowance = currentAllowance - minusDays;

                    documentReference.update("annualHoliday", newHolidayAllowance).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: Fields have been updated successfully.");

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Field have failed to update.");
                        }
                    });

                    return;

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Unavailable");
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

My algorithm which figures out the amount of days picked excluding weekends and returns a final number used to deduct:

```
 public int countDays () {

        CalendarInfo ci = new CalendarInfo();

        final String startYearData = ci.getStartDateYear();
        final String startMonthData = ci.getStartDateMonth();
        final String startDayData = ci.getStartDateDay();

        int setStartDayDate = Integer.parseInt(startDayData);
        int setStartMonthDate = Integer.parseInt(startMonthData);
        int setYearDate = Integer.parseInt(startYearData);

        //beginning
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, setStartDayDate);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, setStartMonthDate);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, setYearDate);
        Date startDates = calendar.getTime();

        final String endMonthData = ci.getEndDateMonth();
        final String endDayData = ci.getEndDateDay();

        int setEndDayDate = Integer.parseInt(endDayData);
        int setEndMonthDate = Integer.parseInt(endMonthData);

        //ending
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, setEndDayDate);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,setEndMonthDate);
        Date endDates = calendar.getTime();
        //
        calendar.setTime(startDates);
        Date dateIterate = null;

        //counters
        int dayCounter = 0;

        while ((dateIterate = calendar.getTime()).before(endDates) || dateIterate.equals(endDates)) {
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            if (day != Calendar.SATURDAY && day != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
                dayCounter++;
                //System.out.println(dateIterate);
            }
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }

        return dayCounter;

    }
```

Comment: Can you please share your firebase firestore data structure?  how is it stored ? A SS or JSON which displays nodes would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `documentReference.addSnapshotListener`, you're adding a permanent listener to that document. This listener gets called right away with the current data for the document, and then it also gets called whenever that data changes.

Now *inside* the `onEvent` of the listener, you call  `documentReference.update`. This changes the data for the document in the database, and thus (as defined above) triggers the listener again. So your `onEvent` gets called again, which once again updates the data, and causes it to trigger again, and again, and again...

If you want to update data without causing such a loop, you have a few options:

1. Use [`get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) instead of `addSnapshotListener`. The `get` method (as its name implies) gets the value of the document only once, and won't be triggered by further changes. This is the simplest fix, as you won't have to change most of your code.
2. Use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to read-and-update the document atomically. This is necessary when the new data in the document depends on the existing data, as seems the case here. The reason you should use a transaction is to prevent other users from changing the data between when you read its value, and when you write back the update.
3. Use an [`increment`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) call to atomically increment or decrement a field value on the server. This is a simpler call than the transaction from before, but I can't immediately see if that would work for your code - as there's quite a lot going on in the `onEvent` call right now.